# Visual Studio ends program instead of highlighting the error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

Specifications

```
Visual Studio 2015 SP 1
.NET 4.0
VB.NET
```

I'm having a weird issue where my program doesn't stop the process and highlight the error point with the convenient popup that I'm used to. Instead the program dumps the error into the Output and I have to look through it to find where the issue is, what it is, and what it was.

This is getting kind of annoying and I wonder if this is a setup issue. My move to VS2015 was recent and I remade the project files so they would be a pure VS2015 project. The debugger was working at first, but it stopped a few days ago. This is the average message I get;

```
The thread 0x2044 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\bin\Debug\ProgramName.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ProgramName.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ProgramName.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\bin\Debug\ToolBoxCS.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x213c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in ProgramName.exe
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>ProgramName.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Specified cast is not valid.</Message><StackTrace>   at ProgramName.Interview.Load_Interview(Int32 Control, String Clientcode) in D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\Class\Interview.vb:line 493
   at ProgramName.frmInterview.frmInterview_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\Applications\frmInterview.vb:line 97
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at ProgramName.Interview.Load_Interview(Int32 Control, String Clientcode) in D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\Class\Interview.vb:line 493
   at ProgramName.frmInterview.frmInterview_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Programming\ProgramName-Download\ProgramName\Applications\frmInterview.vb:line 97
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
The program '[7424] ProgramName.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

The weird part is the code window goes to where the problem is, but the debug stops at the same time without a popup.

So did I accidentally check off some option I really needed or do something stupid that is easy to fix. Is this an issue with my code or maybe a permission setting?

Edit:

Debug mode is on:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire method that is causing the error in a try block to catch an exception?

Comment: You are probably compiling the code as a Release build, without debugging support. Compile it as a Debug build, and run with regular old F5 to attach the debugger. Anyway, the exception trace tells you what you need to fix the problem. You are getting an `InvalidCastException` in your `frmInterview_Load` method, line 97. Look for a cast: it is wrong. Post more code if you need help.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I know what the problem in this case is. I'm adding the Stacktrace in case I'm missing the reason that the IDE won't stop and show the popup. It just ends and dumps stacktrace into output. I like being able to fix the program while it's running. I've added a picture to show that debug is on.

Comment: Check that you didn't have any "global" and `Try.. Catch` blocks which can swallow error and just exit from application

Comment: Another option: Visual Studio on 64-bit machine known of issue which swallow all errors happened in the `Form.Load` event handler. Use @Gavin suggestion and wrap all code inside of `Form.Load` eventhandler in `Try.. Catch` block and put Exception info in `Debug.Print` or `MessageBox`